# NSInternalInconsistencyException Error in MacOSX when running javafx application

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

An error occurs when running a javafx application on my macbook.

I don't know why this is happening.

[Error Log]

/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.18/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=59280:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/sharkvary/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/17.0.2/javafx-controls-17.0.2.jar:/Users/sharkvary/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/17.0.2/javafx-graphics-17.0.2.jar:/Users/sharkvary/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/17.0.2/javafx-base-17.0.2.jar:/Users/sharkvary/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/17.0.2/javafx-fxml-17.0.2.jar -p /Users/sharkvary/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/17.0.2/javafx-graphics-17.0.2-mac.jar:/Users/sharkvary/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/17.0.2/javafx-fxml-17.0.2-mac.jar:/Users/sharkvary/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/17.0.2/javafx-base-17.0.2-mac.jar:/Users/sharkvary/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/17.0.2/javafx-controls-17.0.2-mac.jar:/Users/sharkvary/Dev-sharkvary/workspace-intellij/test/target/classes -m com.example.test/com.example.test.HelloApplication
2023-01-23 23:20:16.248 java[8301:107116] *** Assertion failure in -[_NSTrackingAreaAKViewHelper removeTrackingRect:], _NSTrackingAreaAKManager.m:1602
2023-01-23 23:20:16.251 java[8301:107116] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '0x0 is an invalid NSTrackingRectTag. Common possible reasons for this are: 1. already removed this trackingRectTag, 2. Truncated the NSTrackingRectTag to 32bit at some point.'

*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff81a3f140b __exceptionPreprocess + 242
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007ff819f3de25 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   Foundation                          0x00007ff81b294fb0 -[NSCalendarDate initWithCoder:] + 0
3   AppKit                              0x00007ff81db79490 -[_NSTrackingAreaAKViewHelper removeTrackingRect:] + 190
4   libglass.dylib                      0x00000001306104e9 -[GlassViewDelegate setFrameSize:] + 361
5   libglass.dylib                      0x0000000130615d68 -[GlassView3D setFrameSize:] + 88
6   AppKit                              0x00007ff81d5037f5 -[NSView setFrame:] + 347
7   libglass.dylib                      0x0000000130615dc5 -[GlassView3D setFrame:] + 69
8   AppKit                              0x00007ff81d514645 -[NSView resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 694
9   AppKit                              0x00007ff81d513f76 -[NSView resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 488
10  AppKit                              0x00007ff81d4f363a -[NSView setFrameSize:] + 1460
11  AppKit                              0x00007ff81d5037f5 -[NSView setFrame:] + 347
12  AppKit                              0x00007ff81d514645 -[NSView resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 694
13  AppKit                              0x00007ff81d513f76 -[NSView resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 488
14  AppKit                              0x00007ff81d4f363a -[NSView setFrameSize:] + 1460
15  AppKit                              0x00007ff81d51237a -[NSThemeFrame setFrameSize:] + 482
16  AppKit                              0x00007ff81d511a3c -[NSWindow _oldPlaceWindow:fromServer:] + 813
17  AppKit                              0x00007ff81d50fff1 -[NSWindow _setFrameCommon:display:fromServer:] + 1684
18  libglass.dylib                      0x0000000130607acf -[GlassWindow(Java) _setFlipFrame:display:animate:] + 239
19  libglass.dylib                      0x00000001306075cc -[GlassWindow(Java) _setWindowFrameWithRect:withDisplay:withAnimate:] + 268
20  libglass.dylib                      0x000000013060781b -[GlassWindow(Java) _setBounds:y:xSet:ySet:w:h:cw:ch:] + 571
21  libglass.dylib                      0x00000001306212fe Java_com_sun_glass_ui_mac_MacWindow__1setBounds2 + 446
22  ???                                 0x0000000113b72a10 0x0 + 4625738256
)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

My Info
OS : Ventura 13.1
IDE : IntelliJ Community 2022.3.1
JAVA : openJDK 11 (It is installed by brew)
`openjdk version "11.0.18" 2023-01-17 OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 11.0.18+0) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 11.0.18+0, mixed mode)`
Application : IntelliJ New Project Sample(New Project -> Java FX -> maven -> Next -> Run)

Comment: Include error messages as text, formatted as code, (it is easier to read).

Comment: Try recent software, (JDK 19.0.2, JavaFX 19.0.2.1).  Is it an M MacBook or an Intel MacBook?  What OS version is is running?